# Background-image:url not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background image to a link via the background-image:url like so

```
  <a href="#" style="width:300px; height:125px; background-image:url('http://dev.nclexreview.net/media/3549/livereviewsignin.png')"></a>
```

I have tried inline CSS as well as external CSS.

It works perfectly in a div, but not in an a.

I have tried just using background:url also and had no luck with that either. This is a sprite image, and I want to change the position based on a mouse over, but I can't even get the image to appear in the first place.

I would really appreciate some assistance :)

Comment: Your `a` is empty - it is also an _inline_ element, not a _block_ element.

Comment: "It works perfectly in a , but not in an . " - a what and an what?
And, what browser are you using?

Comment: This code is part of the ascx.cs. @GarethCornish it works perfectly in a div tag but not an a tag? Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "a" tag is an *inline* element, change it's display type to block;

http://jsfiddle.net/qWW68/

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;width:300px; height:125px; background-image:url('http://dev.nclexreview.net/media/3549/livereviewsignin.png')"></a>
```

Because this is a sprite, you will want to move this into an external stylesheet in order to add the pseudo class styles

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the style in a sheet regardless. You can style the a element with the general background and then on a:hover, just use the background-position.